# grep spacing error

Tags: bash, shell

Hi guys i've a problem with grep . I don't know if there is another search code in shell script.
  I'm trying to backup a folder AhmetsFiles which is stored in my Flash Disk , but at the same time I've to group them by their extensions and save them into [extensionName] Folder.

[AhmetsFiles](http://ul.to/rro8u9h7)

> An example : /media/FlashDisk/AhmetsFiles/lecture.pdf must be stored in /home/$(whoami)/Desktop/backups/pdf

Problem is i cant copy a file which name contains spaces.(lecture 2.pptx)
  After this introduction here my code.

```
    filename="/media/FlashDisk/extensions"
    count=0
    exec 3<&0
    exec 0< $filename

    mkdir "/home/$(whoami)/Desktop/backups"

    while read extension
    do
        cd "/home/$(whoami)/Desktop/backups"
        rm -rf "$extension"
        mkdir "$extension"
        cd "/media/FlashDisk/AhmetsFiles"
        files=( `ls | grep -i "$extension"` )
        fCount=( `ls | grep -c -i "$extension"` )
        for (( i=0 ; $i<$fCount ; i++ ))
        do
            cp -f "/media/FlashDisk/AhmetsFiles/${files[$i]}" "/home/$(whoami)/Desktop/backups/$extension"
        done
        let count++
    done

    exec 0<&3

    exit 0
```

Comment: Instead of `/home/$(whoami)` it's better to use `$HOME`. It works even if the homedir is in an unusual location.

Comment: Or `~/Desktop` or some such.

Comment: Thank you for this detail Thomas i ll change my code. Please help me if you know how to ignore spaces in grep search :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your looping is way more complicated than it needs to be, no need for either `ls` or `grep` or the `files` and `fCount` variables:

```
    for file in *.$extension
    do
        cp -f "/media/FlashDisk/AhmetsFiles/$file" "$HOME/Desktop/backups/$extension"
    done
```

This works correctly with spaces.

I'm assuming that you actually wanted to interpret `$extension` as a file extension, not some random string in the middle of the filename like your original code does.

Comment: It can be even simpler: `cp -f -t destination source/*.$extension`

Comment: thank you very much Thomas :) It's working but i dont know how ? I can't understand how it works ?

Comment: `*.whatever` just expands to the list of files matching that pattern, but handles spaces properly. The `for` loop iterates over that. This use of the `for` loop is probably more common than the C-like arithmetic version. See e.g. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you

```
grep -i "$extension" | while IFS=: read x ; do
  cp ..
done
```

instead?

Also, I believe you may prefer something like `grep -i ".$extension$"` instead (anchor it to the end of line).

On the other hand, the most optimal way is probably

```
cp -f /media/FlashDisk/AhmetsFiles/*.$extension "$HOME/Desktop/backups/$extension/"
```